# Get Products By Minimum Duration Between StartDate and EndDate?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having some problem to get distinct products between start-data and end-date and minimum duration. My table structure is,

```
ID   SKU   Desc1   Desc2   Price   PriceFrom   PriceTo
-------------------------------------------------------
1    xxxx  xxxx     xxxx     12     1/1/2014    1/1/2015    
1    xxx   xxxx     xxxx     12     1/1/2014    2/1/2014    
1    xxx   xxxx     xxxx     12     9/1/2014    10/1/2014
```

Let's say today's date is 09/04/2014. So we have 2 options record 1 and 3(because 2 is outside the range of today's date) but I choose 3 because the duration of 3rd record is less than 1st record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `order by` and `top`:

```
select top 1 t.*
from table t
where cast(getdate() as date) >= PriceFrom and cast(getdate() as date) <= PriceTo
order by datediff(day, PriceFrom, PriceTo) asc;
```

**update:**

```
SELECT
    MIN(DATEDIFF(DAY, t.PriceFrom, t.PriceTo)),
    t.ID,
    t.Name,
    t.ModelNumber,
    t.Description,
    t.Price,
    t.NewPrice,
    t.SKU
FROM Products t
WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN PriceFrom AND PriceTo
GROUP BY    t.ID,
            t.Name,
            t.ModelNumber,
            t.Description,
            t.Price,
            t.NewPrice,
            t.SKU
```

Comment: Thanks It works only for 1 product(id=1). I need to do this for other products as well

Comment: Thanks I fix it using Min and Group By